# Silverlight RadGrid Bind Column to Object

Tags: silverlight, telerik, datatemplate, radgrid, custom-type

Simple question....

I have an issue binding a column in RadGrid (SILVERLIGHT) to a  custom type.

My scenario:

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="Grid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsReadOnly="true"  >
 <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
 <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding ID, Mode=OneTime}"  />
 <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Vehicle, Mode=OneTime}"  >
     <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="Name"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellEditTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

where Items is an ObservableCollection of:

```
public class Source
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public Vehicle Vehicle {get; set;}
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public int ID{get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

So ID column is displayed correctly, but Vehicle column is empty...where am I going wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Vehicle, Mode=OneTime}"  >
                <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

using CellTemplate and Not CellEditTemplate i have still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is cut & pasted: You have misspelt `Vehicle` as `Vehilce` in your Source class.

If you check your debug output window it should report any binding errors with enough detail to find this sort of mistake.

Comment: Sorry it's not cut/past. Property name in runtime code it's ok...still having the problem

Comment: @user756037: Care to share? That is the point of the site after all.

Comment: sure:  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vehicle.Name}"></TextBlock>

Comment: @user - you should post the answer as an answer, not a comment, you can then mark it as the answer. An answer buried in a comment is no good to anyone.